# How to make display:flex items go to the next line, automatically?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, display

So am new to learning/using the "display: flex" property.

```css
*{
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-margin:0;
    -webkit-padding:0;
}
.container {
    display: flex;
  }
  
  .imagebox {
    position: relative;
    flex: 1;
    margin: 15px;
  }
  
  .imagebox img {
    max-height: 200px;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="imagebox">
          <a href="#" class="images">
                  <img class="active" src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/000/?text=Image" />
          </a>
        </div>
      
        <div class="imagebox">
          <a href="#" class="images">
            <img class="active" src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/000/?text=Image" />
          </a>
        </div>
      
        <div class="imagebox">
            <a href="#" class="images">
              <img class="active" src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/000/?text=Image" />
            </a>
          </div>

          <div class="imagebox">
            <a href="#" class="images">
              <img class="active" src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/000/?text=Image" />
            </a>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Here are 4 boxes of a certain size but if I insert one more, the size gets smaller as it tries to fit the 5th box in the same line, how to get the 5th box in the next line?

```css
*{
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-margin:0;
    -webkit-padding:0;
}
.container {
    display: flex;
  }
  
  .imagebox {
    position: relative;
    flex: 1;
    margin: 15px;
  }
  
  .imagebox img {
    max-height: 200px;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="imagebox">
          <a href="#" class="images">
                  <img class="active" src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/000/?text=Image" />
          </a>
        </div>
      
        <div class="imagebox">
          <a href="#" class="images">
            <img class="active" src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/000/?text=Image" />
          </a>
        </div>
      
        <div class="imagebox">
            <a href="#" class="images">
              <img class="active" src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/000/?text=Image" />
            </a>
          </div>

          <div class="imagebox">
            <a href="#" class="images">
              <img class="active" src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/000/?text=Image" />
            </a>
          </div>

       <div class="imagebox">
            <a href="#" class="images">
              <img class="active" src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/000/?text=Image" />
            </a>
          </div>
      </div>
```

I want the images to automatically go on to the next line when it reaches the end of the main container, I have tried reducing the width as well, it didn't work.
It's probably something very simple but I can't really seem to find the way, also am not fully accustomed with all the flexbox properties

Comment: Are you looking for [the `flex-wrap` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap)?

Comment: See this https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flexbox

Comment: @Dlk no it doesn't solve, if I keep adding more boxes like till 12, eventually it gets out of view, what I want is that the divs that don't fit, automatically goes on to the next line

Comment: @OishikSengupta Probably because you're mixing `position:absolute` with Flexbox. The items within the flex aren't wide enough to trigger a wrap, and the absolutely-positioned images don't take part in the flexbox calculations. [Flexbox and absolute positioning](https://chenhuijing.com/blog/flexbox-and-absolute-positioning/)

Comment: @Richard Deeming yes, I figured that, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `width` of `.imagebox {}` accordingly

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-margin:0;
    -webkit-padding:0;
}
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  
  .imagebox {
    position: relative;
    margin: 15px;
    width: 20%;
  }
  
  .imagebox img {
    max-height: 200px;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="imagebox">
          <a href="#" class="images">
                  <img class="active" src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/000/?text=Image" />
          </a>
        </div>
      
        <div class="imagebox">
          <a href="#" class="images">
            <img class="active" src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/000/?text=Image" />
          </a>
        </div>
      
        <div class="imagebox">
            <a href="#" class="images">
              <img class="active" src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/000/?text=Image" />
            </a>
          </div>

          <div class="imagebox">
            <a href="#" class="images">
              <img class="active" src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/000/?text=Image" />
            </a>
          </div>

       <div class="imagebox">
            <a href="#" class="images">
              <img class="active" src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/000/?text=Image" />
            </a>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the flex-wrap property:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox doesn't play nicely with absolutely-positioned children. By taking the images out of the normal flow, they no longer take part in the flexbox calculations. The remaining `imagebox` element is not wide enough to trigger wrapping.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 15px;
}

.imagebox {
  flex: 0 0 calc((100% - 45px) / 4);
}

.imagebox img {
  max-height: 200px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="imagebox">
    <a href="#" class="images">
      <img class="active" src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/000/?text=Image" />
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="imagebox">
    <a href="#" class="images">
      <img class="active" src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/000/?text=Image" />
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="imagebox">
    <a href="#" class="images">
      <img class="active" src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/000/?text=Image" />
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="imagebox">
    <a href="#" class="images">
      <img class="active" src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/000/?text=Image" />
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="imagebox">
    <a href="#" class="images">
      <img class="active" src="https://fakeimg.pl/350x200/000/?text=Image" />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```